# ¿Como realizar una acción a través de combinación de teclas cuando el formulario no esta activo o no cuenta con el foco en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy realizando una aplicación en windows form en C# quiero utilizar combinación de teclas para minimizar y maximizar la aplicación, con el KeyPress funciona correctamente pero solo cuando el formulario esta activo, pero quiero que con la combinación de teclas también se pueda abrir el formulario que esta minimizado, busque en Internet y encontré que con hook puedes leer las teclas seleccionadas incluso cuando no esta activo el formulario, pero no me funciona con la combinación de teclas, ¿alguien que me pueda echar la mano? se lo agradecería

Hasta el momento solo uso el Hook, anexo el codigo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    GlobalKeyboardHook gHook;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        gHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook(); // creo un GlobalKeyboardHook
        gHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gHook_KeyDown);// declaro un evento KeyDown 
        // Add the keys you want to hook to the HookedKeys list
        foreach (Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
            gHook.HookedKeys.Add(key);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gHook.hook();//activo el hook 
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gHook.unhook();//desactivo el hook
    }
    // Handle the KeyDown Event

    public void gHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += ((char)e.KeyValue).ToString();

    }

    //con este metodo detecto que el usuario preciono "Control + n" pero no esta ligado al hook
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(keyData) == Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control) + Convert.ToInt32(Keys.N))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Se ha pulsado la combinación de teclas Control+N");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

mi problema ahora es como ligar el evento para detectar el "control + n" al hook, no se si me la estoy complicando o voy por buen camino, si alguien puede ayudar, lo agradeceria bastante

Comment: Si la aplicación está minimizada no va a recibir las combinaciones de teclas. Tienes que hacerlo con el hook que mencionas, que captura eventos del sistema. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: he seguido buscando y estas en lo correcto, solo que no he podido saber como detectar por ejemplo el "control + n" me detecta solo la pulsación de una tecla a la vez, ¿sabes como le podría hacer?

Comment: muestra el codigo. apretar la tecla crtl no deberia levantar el metodo key press...

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya agregue el código que utilizo, GlobalKeyboardHook es la clase de hook que utilizo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

```
    /* Estas líneas de código, se basan en los valores de los parámetros,
     ordena al compilador que declare una función residente en el archivo
     User32.dll, la cual obtiene el registro de las teclas pulsadas. */

    //Llama al método para registrar las teclas pulsadas.
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

    //Al cerrar el formulario deja de enviar los resultados, deja de registrar las teclas pulsadas.
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    //Valores de las teclas pulsadas por el sistema MOD_CONTROL para la tecla Control y WM_HOTKEY que puede ser cualquier tecla alfanumérica.
    const int MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002;
    const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

    //Llama al método al iniciar el formulario.
    //this.Handle, sirve para identificar el ejecutable de cual se llama.
    //0, es un identificador, en caso de querer agregar mas combinaciones seria de 0 a N números.
    //MOD_CONTROL, valor para la combinación de Control + ValorTecla
    //(int)Keys.N, valor de la tecla pulsada y convertida a entero. 
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0, MOD_CONTROL, (int)Keys.N);
    }

    //Cierra el registro al salir del formulario.
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0);
    }

    //Pregunta por la tecla pulsada y si cumple con el parámetro dado a la combinación que en este caso es 0, entra y muestra el mensaje de texto si se cumple.
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Se ha pulsado la combinación de teclas Control + N");
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: estaría de lujo si pudieras explicar el código. :D

Comment: Listo, espero que te ayude, cualquier duda, aquí estamos. :P

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en resolver mi duda, me fue muy útil :)

Comment: Me surgió una duda, como saber o como identificar otra letra que no sea la "N" por ejemplo la "C" , veo que para comparar la "N" utiliza (int)m.WParam == 0, ¿hay alguna referencia que me puedan proporcionar para entender como identificar cualquier letra?

Comment: Por ejemplo para la letra "C" se agrega al método de Form1_Load otra linea para registrar la combinación de teclas que seria asi: RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, MOD_CONTROL, (int)Keys.C); el segundo parámetro ahora seria 1, y en Keys la letra "C", en el método WndProc se haría otra condición pero esta vez cambiamos (int)m.WParam == 1.